# C# Visual Studio Unit Tests no Longer run in one repo but does in the other: Same Service Application code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

Hi this is more of a conceptual question so sorry I don't think code example will help.

Anyways, we have two different versions of a code in gitlab. The code within the the two builds (master, dev) are the same. However the master branch's unit tests won't run. Again the codes are the same. The master branch unit test when you try to debug one test, actually tries to run the entire service application.

On Dev, test tests an indivual test. and debug will debug just the part of the code that is called in the unit test.

Why could this be happening? I get no warnings from VS2019 either

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Client;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Client.Util;

namespace ClientTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ODFSClientTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestGetLogFilesInfo()
        {
            ConstantsUtil constants = new ConstantsUtil();
            constants.InitializeConfiguration();

            var logFilesInfo = Producer.GetSourceLogFilesInfo();

            Assert.AreEqual(7, logFilesInfo.Count);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestGetSourceLogFilesInfoRTD1240s()
        {
            ConstantsUtil constants = new ConstantsUtil();
            constants.InitializeConfiguration();

            var logFilesInfo = Producer.GetSourceLogFilesInfoRTD1240s();

            Assert.AreEqual(3, logFilesInfo.Count);
        }
```

Comment: Obviously the code isn't the same. VS doesn't know anything about the branches themselves, it only sees the code in the working directory. If you compare the two git branches what are the differences? How are you trying to run the tests?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What do you mean how am I trying to run them? I right click on the test method and click run. Okay let me update my question with a sample code of the test method

Comment: Then there's no way the entire application will start. Unless the test actually does this. Diff the branches instead of posting your code. Git can tell you what the difference is immediately.

Comment: Ok, I've added the the test code inside my OP @PanagiotisKanavos This is how they all are. This how the tests are in both builds. the only thing is that one runs as it should, the other doesn't. The code is the same, I guess a configuration changed but I don't know what.  VS doesn't warn me at all

Comment: Diff the branches. it's impossible to guess what your project looks like, how. your project files, setting files differ from one branch to the other. Diff will tell you immediately. Perhaps the `csproj` files refer to different versions of the Test SDK? Have you upgraded VS recently? Upgraded NuGet packages on only one branch?

Comment: Yeah I want to do that... How can you diff branches? I'm new to coding and this is a service I inherited. Only thing I know to do is beyond compare application

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just diffed them in GIT and it only shows me code changes I made. And that's it. Nothing else config wise that would stop it from running the unit tests. I am missing some extra tests in dev but that's it. Nothing that would stop the code from running

Comment: So the branches aren't the same after all. But you still didn't explain what the difference is. How can people guess what's going on on your machine??? If you upgrade VS, you also need to upgrade the VS Test SDK package used by your unit test projects, otherwise the tests can't be found by the runner. You'll actually see in the build output whether the tests were found or not

Comment: Or perhaps the code differences include code that causes exceptions in eg the test constructors, which means the tests can't be loaded.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the code differences are very minor. they use the same logic. Now the question you ask about the Test SDK package is something I don't know. I'm so new to this I don't know. I do know that I cloned the branch from the same repo and continued the app on a different machine... Which I guess might have a different version of VS2019. But in the output, window of VS2019, it doesn't tell me anything about not being able to find the tests. No warnings. Nothing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So I restarted visual studio and that fixed it. But this raises another question on what you mentioned. say I end up upgrading my VS later on, how would one update the Test SDK package? How do I even know what my test SDK package is? I thought it was updated automatically as it sounds that test packages would come by default in VS2019?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted Visual Studio. And that somehow fixed it

Comment: It seems that your problem has been solved, so please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).